# How to Create domain name instead of using ip address in local application with haproxy?

Tags: tcp, ip, haproxy, domain-name

I want to ask if there is a solution for using example.com instead of using ip:port in application launched on my local pc or server ?
Is haproxy do can do that ? or there is another free tools that can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to configure Haproxy to route requests based on a specific domain name to your local server/homelab. Use Access Control Lists Mapping (ACL) [Here](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/how-to-map-domain-names-to-backend-server-pools-with-haproxy#access-control-list-mapping), then you need to configure the DNS name to point to the IP address of your local server (if you are in a local network or using a local PC, ensure that your router is configured to perform port forwarding to your local server.)